# How can I get the outdated expo docs?

Tags: react-native, expo

As our RN application based on react-native@0.61.5, so we use expo@^0.37.0 to set up local development environment. But it seems that expo doesn't supply outdated docs, could only find recent version docs https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/.

Answer (score 1):

Old docs often get lost, but thankfully there are a few ways of finding the old pages.

The first option is using the Wayback Machine from archive.org. The [expo.dev](https://web.archive.org/web/20210801000000*/https://expo.dev/) site seems to go back to late 2020. A problem might be that some pages aren't crawled and might be missing.

And because it seems that their docs are [open source](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/main/docs) with some commits going back three years. So you could in theory pull an old commit and build / run the docs locally.

Answer (score 1):

You can use webarchive and old URL for documentation https://docs.expo.io.
In your case it is http://web.archive.org/web/20210305044934/https://docs.expo.io/versions/v37.0.0/ but not all pages are supported:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use github online editor to check the outdate markdown docs is an optional solution.
Such as link: https://github.dev/expo/expo/blob/sdk-37/docs/pages/versions/unversioned/sdk/calendar.md#L1

[image]